# sending gmp type mpf_t using openMPI

Tags: c, gmp, openmpi

What is the best way (fast and relatively simple to implement) to send `gmp` of type `mpf_t` using `MPI` (in c)?
a simple code will be helpful.

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [send array of mpz\_t over mpi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280359/send-array-of-mpz-t-over-mpi)

Comment: @HristoIliev, this is about `mpf_t` (floating) and my question/answer was about `mpz_t` (integer), so no duplicate. Only `mpz_t` type havs export and import.

Comment: Yes, just saw that GMP does not support exporting and importing floating-point numbers and retracted the vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mpf_t uses several pointers, so you should serialize mpf_t (and other GMP types) before sending via MPI.

There were some letters about MPI in GMP mailing list: https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2008-March/003091.html

There is article about MPI wrapper library for GMP (MPIGMP + MPIBNCpack): http://na-inet.jp/na/bnc/brief_intro_mpibncpack.pdf

Also there were solution of mpf_t serialization into file, you can reuse it to serialize into byte array and send it over MPI: [How to serialize the GMP mpf type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318979/how-to-serialize-the-gmp-mpf-type) (explained in https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2007-November/002981.html)